# the default apache page won't show from outside network

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, apache-2.4

I have a server and ubuntu is installed on it as OS. i connected to server via SSH and installed apache2.4 on the server and it ran successfully. i typed

```
curl 127.0.0.1
```

on the terminal and the apache's default html page appeared on terminal.
but i was wondering if i could see the default apache page from my computer by using server's ip as the url in the browser on my computer, but nothing just appeared.
I searched a lot but nothing found. i tried to off the firewall of ubuntu by

```
sudo ufw disable
```

but it didnt work. and i just used those commands that is related to `iptables`
allows the incomming http requests and they also didn't work.

So what's the problem ?!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Listen directive in Apache configuration. It may be set to only open a socket on the localhost (127.0.0.1) interface:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
```

Try changing it to

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
```

Comment: there is "Listen 80" on the "ports.conf" that indicates it's listening on all interfaces and in "000-default.conf" file there is also "<VirtualHost *:80>...." and still not working.

Comment: when on the server, does curl against the server's real IP work ?

Comment: i didnt get your question exactly, but if you mean "curl server-ip-address" works or not, it works on server.

Comment: that means the reason you can't get from your computer to the web site on your server isn't due to your server configuration. something in the middle- the server infrastructure or hosting provider or something related to your local network- is getting in the way.

Comment: Try listening on a different port, like 8000, and see what gets through and what does not.

Comment: Nothing changed. "curl ip-address:8000" work on server but not from outside.

Comment: If you can get to other ports on the server, like ssh port 22, but not to ports used by http, then the either your isp or your server service provider are running proxies or otherwise filtering access for some reason. To resolve that you will have to engage with them.

Comment: actually i used trial cloudsigma.com servers to test this, can you check that if you can find exactly what's wrong ?!

Comment: looks like they have 24/7 live support. best to ask them why you can't see an http service your server is running. there is probably a configuration switch, they will identify it right away.